# Cloning content types and corresponding Display Suite settings

Tags: nodes, display-suite

I need to clone a content type, so I choose to do that with module: [Bundle copy](https://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy).

I need to clone Display Suite settings of my bundle as well. How would I clone that? (Found a patch that enables that with Bundle copy: https://drupal.org/node/2055157). Wondering is there any better solution?

Comment: Hello. Pooling questions are not so good here. And having 3 of them asked as one is not really the best approach either.

Comment: Hi guys! How about this? Just edited the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, found a solution:

1. [Bundle copy](https://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) version 7.x-2.x-dev allows cloning directly (without exporting/importing and changing bundle's machine name).
2. There is a [patch](https://drupal.org/node/2055157) that gives support for display suite cloning, exporting and importing. (I had to fix the patch first to be able to apply it with patch manager.)

All worked like a charm!